# Repositioning background image on smaller width screen

Tags: html, css

I'm not a seasoned web developer and am quickly hacking up something for fun. I have a web page that has an 1024 x 768 background image (I know that's probably a bad idea) that I can correctly centre if the browser width increases. However, when the browser width decreases below 768px, I want the image to be "centered" along with the width rather than just tacking the top left corner so that the centre of the image is always in line with the other elements on the page.

What kind of CSS magic can pull this off?

Here's my CSS:

```
body
    {
    background: #000000; /*Black bg for extra space not covered by img*/
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;

}

.wrap
{
    background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
    /*Stretch body all the way to edges*/
    /*width: 1024px; /*Min width for site*/

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: try media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

follow tutorials for responsive :

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this website](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)
The CSS shown here in the "Awesome, Easy, Progressive CSS3 Way" is almost as the code you have. what you need to change to center the image horizontal and vertical is adding "center center" to the background settings:

```
.wrap{
  background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

along with all your other css. This will ensure that the background image that you are using will stretch to fit the screen size(height and width-wise)